# Will the debate over smallest entity possible ever end?

Tags: soft-question

I think that we can't find the smallest possible entity because more sub particles would be consequently discovered.

Will the debate ever end?

Comment: you're asking how long we will keep discovering things in a given field of physics... I don't know how anyone is expected to answer this

Comment: @Alex Robinson So tell me how can anyone reach the smallest entity possible

Comment: What "confusion"?  Who is confused, and what specifically are they confused about?  How are we supposed to determine how long we will keep asking questions?  Would that not depend on the answers we get to our current questions?

Comment: I don't find this edit really cleared things up... What "debate"?  Who is debating about this?  Is there context missing here?  Are you trying to ask if we'll ever _know_ if there's a smallest possible entity?

Comment: @JMac Yes I am asking if we'll ever know if there's a smallest possible entity?

Comment: In my opinion, most physicists do *not* believe that there is an infinite tower of particles within particles. However, I don’t think we can ever be sure. All we can do is build models that reproduce what we are able to observe. Currently we cannot “see” anything inside an electron, so we assume it is fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

By any reasonable definition, the "smallest entity possible" is a point particle, which occupies zero volume and therefore cannot have any internal structure (i.e. it looks like a point at *all* scales).

So there isn't a debate over what the "smallest entity possible" is: it's a point particle (aside from semantic arguments about the meaning of the word "possible"). But this is most likely not what you're actually asking.

Based on the comments, the question you *actually* appear to be asking is: do we "know" if the particles that we declare to be point particles today are *truly* point particles, at all scales?

And the answer is: **we know that the electron (for example) is a point particle in exactly the same sense in which we know anything else in science**.

In science, knowledge is determined by gathering interpreting experimental data. When we say that we "know" a particular fact, what we mean is that all of the experimental data we have ever taken is consistent with that fact. This necessarily means that what we know can change from time to time, as we gather more data and learn more about the world. That's what learning ultimately means, after all - it's a process of gathering and refining knowledge.

We know that the electron is a point particle because no matter how hard we have tried in the past to discover any internal structure whatsoever in it, we have found nothing. At all scales that we have been able to measure, it looks like a point particle, and all predictions that assume it *is* a point particle have been verified to within present experimental uncertainty.

This is somewhat different than the sense in which the word "know" is used outside of science: typically, when someone says that they "know" something, they mean something much more absolute - they're certain that the fact is true, and no amount of extra information could make it untrue.

In practice, such absolute certainty can only exist about fields of knowledge which are entirely decoupled from observations of nature - axiomatic fields like mathematics, for example, where the *only* inputs to a particular chain of reasoning are axioms that are *assumed* to be certainly true. Any time you make conclusions using observations of nature as inputs, you will run into the exact same uncertainty, no matter what. **This is the inevitable price of building knowledge on experimental evidence**.

One of the great strengths of the field of science, and why it's been so successful at explaining and making predictions about the natural world, is that it *explicitly acknowledges* this uncertainty, and requires that anything that we know must ultimately be backed by sufficiently strong experimental evidence. This is a **higher** standard of verification for knowledge than is used in many other disciplines; for example, when you try to "do science" without obeying this requirement, you end up with pseudoscience.

In summary: if you use the scientific definition of "know", we know that the electron is a point particle. If you use the colloquial definition of "know", then science can't tell us we know anything.